# How to access a native UIView inside Unity 2D or 3D

Tags: c#, android, ios, react-native, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a plug-in for Unity (c#), which accesses the native Apis and their callbacks (from native to Unity).
How can I place my native View (iOS/Android View) to the Unity game View?

I have created a ground view in Unity and added a player over the ground view, same I want to add a native UIView (iOS and Android) to the ground view.

Comment: If possible with react-native (instance of native iOS and Android)also helps. I means to create a plug-in in react-native instance of native (iOS/Android) will also help